# Was there a clear consensus on gender neutral edits?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Following [How do we feel about gender specific terms?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3285/28141) I surmise that editing in gender neutral wordings is not appreciated.

In the case of [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87805/28141) however, I believe it is one gender neutral edit away from becoming a better question.

- It doesn't need a point of view.

There's no reason it should be considered from either person's sexual representation. The answer(s) would apply in any cases.

- It could be on-topic

<del>There seems to be [some intent on closing it.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87805/how-to-not-fall-in-love-with-my-co-author#comment222126_87805)</del> It is now closed. I'm not familiar with on-topicness here but would it be less appealing for closure, being more of a generic question about a possibly common scenario in this specific aspect of academia?

Comment: Actually, I'd have voted to close even if the question were expressed in a gender neutral way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The consensus seems pretty clear from the votes on answers to

- [How do we feel about gender specific terms?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/how-do-we-feel-about-gender-specific-terms)
- [Gendered pronoun usage](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/gendered-pronoun-usage)

There seems to be far more support for "do as you like in your own posts, don't insist on gender neutrality in other people's posts" than any other policy that has been proposed so far.

The particular question you reference was not closed for being gender-specific, so there's no reason to think that your edit would help it be received better here.

In general, including specific details in a question is not reason to close it, if there's a good general underlying question to be answered. Similarly, it's usually not necessary to remove specific details from a question, unless they are lengthy or otherwise a distraction from the general question. In this question, that does not appear to be the case.